# Input a matrix from user in python

Tags: python

```
rows = int(input("Enter No. of rows>>>"))
columns = int(input('Enter No. of columns>>>'))
l=[0]*columns
l2=[]
for x in range(rows):
    l2.append(l)
print(l2)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(4):
        print('enter',i,'x',j,'entry:')
        l2[i][j] = int(input())

print(l2)
```

This code print similar values in l2. For example if user enters `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` it produces a result with `[[9, 10, 11, 1], [9, 10, 11, 1], [9, 10, 11, 1]]` How do i fix this please help

Comment: What is your desire output

Comment: for example if the user inputs [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]] the output yields [[9,10,11,12],[9,10,11,12],[9,10,11,12]]

Comment: All values must be similar or not?

Comment: No i want to be printed what the user inputs

Comment: Added code blocks

Comment: @zeusequinox Your code does not do what you say. An `IndexError` is raised after entering `5`.

Answer (score 0):

`l2.append(l)` , This line reference one list many time. 
If any value of `l` is change all values in reference are changes at the same time
replace this line with

```
l2.append(l+[])
```